# Need to make a particular filter on a list (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, collections

I have 2 lists with 2 differents Object.

First list ==>
data class ObjectA (
val id: String?,
val label: String?,
val dueDate: LocalDate?
)

And
Second list ==>
data class ObjectB (
val id: String = "",
val clientLabel: String = "",
val productLabel: String = "",
val amount: ColoredAmount
)

And I need to filter the ObjectA list with the ID common values between ObjectB List and ObjectA.

I don't find the simple solution.

Thanks very much for your help.

Regards
Bomatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simplest approach I could find. The lists are named *listA* and *listB*:

```
var filteredList = listA.filter { objectA -> listB.any{ objectB -> objectB.id == objectA.id} }
```

I'll try to decompose and explain it step by step:

1. `listA.filter { objectA -> ... }`traverses objects in *listA* (renamed as *objectA*) and returns a new list containing only the objects that fulfill the condition on the right (...)
2. `istB.any{ objectB -> objectB.id == objectA.id}`returns a boolean indicating if ANY of the objects in *listB* (renamed as *objectB*) fulfill the condition of "being equal to the id of *objectA*"

So overall, for each object on *listA* you traverse *listB* to check if it contains and item with the same ID.

Hope it helps. Filtering lists can be complex to understand at first, so if you have any question leave them in the comment and I'll try to help again.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's a good code for me.

Comment: @BomatchEric Glad that I could help :) by the way could you mark it as the correct answer please? I want to get certified and I need the points

Comment: Hi Raaaaac,how can I mark it as the correct answer ?
By check your answer ?

Comment: @BomatchEric Yes, thank you!! I got my account approved thanks to this :)